# Date Format issue while copying mails from outlook to excel

Tags: excel, email, outlook

I'm trying to copy emails or just a single email at times from outlook and paste into excel but the date formats is different in each row which includes mails from below list. Have been asked to achieve this to calculate ageing of tickets assigned to team. How do I make today, yesterday and last week email to show the proper date (like its in 2 week's before) when copied from outlook to excel. I did search in the internet for solutions but nothing has resolved. I've never done tasks like this before and would suggest any tips or points to resolve the issue.

1. today
2. yesterday
3. last week
4. 2 week's before

Among the above,

> only 2 weeks before email date format is correct

and the other one's looks like in below image. If you see here,

- Today's email is shown just with time alone.
- Yesterday's email with day and time
- Last week's email with day and date
- 2 week's before email with proper date

[image: How data looks when copied from outlook]

I have also tried the **format painter option in excel**. When its applied from 2 week's before to today's one - the output is shown as *1/1/1900* like in below image. How do I proceed ?

Please find attached image  where i have tried formula for date fields but still not getting desired results for today's email, yesterday's email and one week before email. They all give outputs as #VALUE!.
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(C15,"mm-dd-yyyy"))

[image: Format painter doesn't help for today's date]

[image]

Comment: 1/1/1900 is a representation of 0, ...try pasting the content into Notepad first, so you can look at the raw data you're copying.

Comment: No, I'm not getting 1/1/1900 in excel while copying from Outlook itself. It's coming only when I try to format today's date with format of 2 weeks before date column. Hope i didn't misunderstand your point.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a mess with formatting sometimes a workaround could be to use a csv file instead of xlsx or are you using excel for other purposes than saving the emails?

Edit:
You could try to use this function or something similar, so you force excel to show it the way you want:

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"mm-dd-yyyy"))
```

This is the format of the date:
"mm-dd-yyyy"
you can change this in various ways like: "dd:mm:yyyy" and "yy-mm-dd"
d:days
m:month
y:year

All excel dates is a value so when excel gives you 00-01-1900 as the date the cell value is 0. As an example 44771 is 29-07-2022. So when you get that date it is probably because the value of the cell is 0.

Comment: Ater copying the mail from Outlook, team would add a column for current date and calculate the ageing of all tickets in team. So i have to use excel for that purpose.

Comment: I made an edit you could try the function I suggested or an iteration of it

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask this but don't know. You have given k342  - it indicates the column for which I need formatting right ?  For example - C3 in my case which has date as 11:39 PM and provided the formula as like below 
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(C3;"dd-mm-åååå"))  but getting an error like "There is a problem with the formula"..
Even when I change formula to =DATEVALUE(TEXT(C3, "dd-mm-åååå"))  //replaced semi-colon with a comma, even then the output is #VALUE!.. Can you please help. I'm not very good with the excel formulas.

Comment: Sorry my bad K342 is the cell refference, I just copied a function I had in a sheet with a similar problem. You can change that to A1 to get the upper leftcorner of the spreadsheet. A-->z... is columns 1-->1000.... is rows. I have danish formatting that might be the issue forgot to change that. try: =DATEVALUE(TEXT(K342,"mm-dd-yyyy"))
In the function the format is changed by the lettes d:day
M:month
Y:year

Comment: I edited my original question. Please check, its still not working Christoffer.

Comment: The issue with the first one in your edit is that it is a time value and not a date, that would probably require some vba. maybe you could use a combination of the =today() function and =TIMEVALUE(TEXT(F3,"hh:mm AM/PM")) for formatting but i am not sure.
For the other ones I don't know a function from the top of my head. but I would search for something like date time formatting excel. I hope this points you in a direction.